# CUDA - linking errors with convolution example

Tags: c++, linker, cuda

I'm trying to compile the following code by Joe Stam (convolutionapproaches, project with vs2005, I am using VS2010 but compiling with 9.0 engine)

> 1>ConvolutionCudaFunctions.obj : error
>   LNK2019: unresolved external symbol
>   _cudaEventDestroy@4 referenced in function "float _cdecl
>   NaiveGlobalConvolution(unsigned char
>   *,unsigned char *,unsigned int,unsigned int,unsigned
>   int,int,int)"
>   (?NaiveGlobalConvolution@@YAMPAE0IIIHH@Z)
>   1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved
>   external symbol _cudaEventDestroy@4
>   1>ConvolutionCudaFunctions.obj : error
>   LNK2019: unresolved external symbol
>   _cudaEventElapsedTime@12 referenced in function "float _cdecl
>   NaiveGlobalConvolution(unsigned char
>   *,unsigned char *,unsigned int,unsigned int,unsigned
>   int,int,int)"
>   (?NaiveGlobalConvolution@@YAMPAE0IIIHH@Z)
>   1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved
>   external symbol
>   _cudaEventElapsedTime@12 1>ConvolutionCudaFunctions.obj : error
>   LNK2019: unresolved external symbol
>   _cudaEventSynchronize@4 referenced in function "float _cdecl
>   NaiveGlobalConvolution(unsigned char
>   *,unsigned char *,unsigned int,unsigned int,unsigned
>   int,int,int)"
>   (?NaiveGlobalConvolution@@YAMPAE0IIIHH@Z)
>   1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved
>   external symbol
>   _cudaEventSynchronize@4 1>ConvolutionCudaFunctions.obj : error
>   LNK2019: unresolved external symbol
>   _cudaGetLastError@0 referenced in function "float _cdecl
>   NaiveGlobalConvolution(unsigned char
>   *,unsigned char *,unsigned int,unsigned int,unsigned
>   int,int,int)"
>   (?NaiveGlobalConvolution@@YAMPAE0IIIHH@Z)
>   1>ConvolutionCudaFunctions.obj : error
>   LNK2019: unresolved external symbol
>   _cudaConfigureCall@32 referenced in function "float _cdecl
>   NaiveGlobalConvolution(unsigned char
>   *,unsigned char *,unsigned int,unsigned int,unsigned
>   int,int,int)"
>   (?NaiveGlobalConvolution@@YAMPAE0IIIHH@Z)
>   1>ConvolutionCudaFunctions.obj : error
>   LNK2019: unresolved external symbol
>   _cudaEventRecord@8 referenced in function "float _cdecl
>   NaiveGlobalConvolution(unsigned char
>   *,unsigned char *,unsigned int,unsigned int,unsigned
>   int,int,int)"
>   (?NaiveGlobalConvolution@@YAMPAE0IIIHH@Z)
>   1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved
>   external symbol _cudaEventRecord@8
>   1>ConvolutionCudaFunctions.obj : error
>   LNK2019: unresolved external symbol
>   _cudaEventCreate@4 referenced in function "float _cdecl
>   NaiveGlobalConvolution(unsigned char
>   *,unsigned char *,unsigned int,unsigned int,unsigned
>   int,int,int)"
>   (?NaiveGlobalConvolution@@YAMPAE0IIIHH@Z)
>   1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved
>   external symbol _cudaEventCreate@4
>   1>ConvolutionCudaFunctions.obj : error
>   LNK2019: unresolved external symbol
>   _cudaMemset@12 referenced in function "float _cdecl
>   NaiveGlobalConvolution(unsigned char
>   *,unsigned char *,unsigned int,unsigned int,unsigned
>   int,int,int)"
>   (?NaiveGlobalConvolution@@YAMPAE0IIIHH@Z)
>   1>ConvolutionCudaFunctions.obj : error
>   LNK2019: unresolved external symbol
>   _cudaSetupArgument@12 referenced in function "void _cdecl
>   **device_stub__Z28NaiveGlobalConvolutionKernelPhS_jjjf(unsigned
>   char *,unsigned char *,unsigned
>   int,unsigned int,unsigned int,float)"
>   (?__device_stub__Z28NaiveGlobalConvolutionKernelPhS_jjjf@@YAXPAE0IIIM@Z)
>   1>ConvolutionCudaFunctions.obj : error
>   LNK2019: unresolved external symbol
>   ___cudaRegisterVar@32 referenced in function "void _cdecl
>   _*sti***_cudaRegisterAll_59_tmpxft_00000a3c_00000000_3_ConvolutionCudaFunctions_cpp1_ii_imgTex(void)"
>   (?**sti_**_cudaRegisterAll_59_tmpxft_00000a3c_00000000_3_ConvolutionCudaFunctions_cpp1_ii_imgTex@@YAXXZ)
>   1>ConvolutionCudaFunctions.obj : error
>   LNK2019: unresolved external symbol
>   ___cudaRegisterTexture@28 referenced in function "void _cdecl

... a lot of other errors...

> 1>Debug/ConvTest.exe : fatal error
>   LNK1120: 35 unresolved externals

This with /MDd for code generation and CUDA C/C++ Runtime Host library.

If I switch to /MTd for both is the same.

What's wrong with this? I tried both the 32 bit and the 64 bit SDK, the toolkit is 6

Comment: Have you linked to cudart.lib?

Comment: Looks like it does not find the right cudart library. How are you linking ? what parameters? Can you compile the SDK ? which rules are you using?

Comment: I can compile the sdk, and cudart.lib is linked, I installed a 64 bit version of the toolkit and the sdk does not work in either 32/64 versions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a problem with 32/64 bit sdks, I solved by linking with the 32 bit